# Grub2, is it possible to change adapter (as reported by videofinfo from grubs command line)

Tags: grub, resolution

As the title suggests, I'm shown 3 different adapter types when I enter the 'videoinfo' command from grubs terminal:

Adapter 'Cirrus CLDG 5446 PCI Video Driver'
no info available
Adapter 'Bochs PCI Video Driver'
no info available
Adapter 'EFI GOP Driver'
0X000 800 x 600 x 32 (3200) Direct color.
* 0X000 1024 x 768 x 32 (4096 Direct color.
0X000 1280 x 1024 x 32 (5120 Direct color.

I've tried to set grubs display resolution to 1920x1080 in /etc/default/grub but the current adapter doesn't support it so it defaults to 1024x768.
I'm running EndeavourOS (arch based) 6.5.5-arch1-1 with an nvidia gtx 750 ti and proprietry drivers installed efi boot.
On manjaro and mint this was easyily done through editing /etc/default/grub and update-grub
but not so with EndeavorOS as grub reports only the above resolutions with the given adapter.
Setting it to 1280 x 1024 is ok but everything is squished including all the os icons which look weird.

Basically is it possible to change grubs' adapter to support a higher resolution without replacing / reinstalling grub?

Been searching for a couple of days now and haven't found anything specific to changing the adapter if it's even at all possible, if that's the case I'll just lump it hah.
If anyone has any pointers or if it's a solid 'no it's not possible' I would appreciate it.
Thanks for reading this far ('-' )